# Is there a way to prevent Slack application from automatically shutting down?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am building a bot application for Slack with Python using the RTM API which I am currently running in a workspace channel. The problem I have is that it automatically shuts down after a while without any sort of interaction, is there anyway to keep it running indefinitely?

This is the code I use to launch the RTM Client:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
slack_client = slack.RTMClient(
    token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, run_async=True, loop=loop
)
loop.run_until_complete(slack_client.start())
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Can you please add more detail to explain what you mean by "it automatically shuts down after a while". Is Slack closing the websocket? Are you getting any errors? Please also add the relevant part of your code.

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe it is the web socket. I don't get any errors, the bot simply goes offline. I've updated the post with the code I use to launch the RTM Client.